# .NetCore Dropdown Blank in Razor View using ViewBag Example

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-2.0

I have taken this Dropdown example in .NetCore 2.1 back to basics.  I just can't see what I am doing wrong.  The Dropdown is always blank, yet from Debug, I can see that the data is reaching it.  For some reason and clearly the cause, the asp-items collection in the browser is showing 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectList' not the actual values.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag helper is not triggering at all.

The [`@addTagHelper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1#addtaghelper-makes-tag-helpers-available) directive makes Tag Helpers available to the view.Check if the following code is in *Views/_ViewImports.cshtml* file

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Comment: Thanks, that did ultimately fix it.  Just for others awareness to save hours, ones you add this, I needed to rebuild my solution.  It was not working for whatever reason with a simple build.